# Excel - Make a graph that shows number of occurrences of each value in a column

Tags: excel

I am trying to make a graph (like a bar graph, number of occurrences on the y and value on the x) that will show each value in a column and the number of times it occurs. How will I do this?

I am using Excel 2013

Comment: Have you tried summarizing it using a pivot table then graph it?

Comment: No, how would I do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is probably a better way to do this, but this is a working example. Let's assume this is your data:

```
+---+
| 4 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 7 |
| 7 |
| 8 |
| 9 |
+---+
```

Copy this column and paste it into column B. Highlight it and hit `Remove Duplicates`. In `C1`, paste this formula: `=COUNTIF(A:A;B1)` (Use a `;` in Excel 2010+, otherwise use a `,`). In the bottom right corner of `C1`, click the black square and drag it down until you've reached the bottom of column B.

Now your spreadsheet should look something like this (except with the formula result rather than the formula itself):

```
+---+---+------------------+
| A | B |        C         |
+---+---+------------------+ // Actual values of column C
| 4 | 4 | =COUNTIF(A:A;B1) | // 2
| 4 | 5 | =COUNTIF(A:A;B2) | // 1
| 5 | 6 | =COUNTIF(A:A;B3) | // 1
| 6 | 7 | =COUNTIF(A:A;B4) | // 3
| 7 | 8 | =COUNTIF(A:A;B5) | // 1
| 7 | 9 | =COUNTIF(A:A;B6) | // 1
| 7 |   |                  |
| 8 |   |                  |
| 9 |   |                  |
+---+---+------------------+
```

Finally, create a graph as you normally would. Make your `Legend Entries (Series)` your column C, and your `Horizontal (Category) Axis Labels` column B.

This will result in a graph looking like this:
[image: Resulting Graph]

Comment: Just a small note: In the Excel 2010 I am using, function parameters are separated by `;` and not by `,`, so for me it is: `=COUNTIF(A:A;B1)`. This might have changed with Excel 2013 of course...

Comment: Thanks @joergl, I've updated the answer accordingly. I'm actually on Excel 2007!

Comment: In Office 365 ProPlus today, it's a comma.

Comment: could you please explain in more detail what you mean by "Finally, create a table as you normally would"?

Comment: @Robert, I have reworded my answer to be a bit more clear. I have replaced one instance of the word "table" with "spreadsheet", and the other with "graph".

Comment: use `=UNIQUE(A:A)` in cell B1 so you don't have to select column A, copy, paste into column B, select it, goto ribbon and hit "remove duplicates', etc...every time the data in column A changes.